# jqGrid context menu when a grid has no rows, and inside a dialog window

Tags: jqgrid

I have two questions reagarding context menu for [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start):

1. I have an empty grid, and I want a context menu to appear when I click on the grid itself, or on the columns header, currently the context menu is only when I have rows inside the grid. So how can I do this?
2. I have another grid inside a dialog window:

   ```
   $('#company_grid').contextMenu('grid_contextmenu', {
       bindings: {
           'add_row': function(t)
           {
           },

           'delete_row': function(t)
           {
           }
       });
       $(function()
       {
           $( "#company" ).dialog(
           {
               autoOpen: false,
               height: 500,
               width: 900,
               modal: true,
               resizable: false,
               open: function(event, ui)
               {
                   $("#company").setGridWidth($(this).width()-2 );
                   $("#company").setGridHeight($(this).height()-100);
               }
           });
       });

   <div id="company">
       <table id="company_grid"></table>
   </div>
   <div class="contextMenu" id="grid_contextmenu">
       <ul>
           <li id="add_row">&nbsp;Add Row&nbsp;</li>
           <li id="delete_row">&nbsp;Delete Row&nbsp;</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   ```

When the dialog is opened, I can't see the context menu. I realized that it appears behind the dialog. So what am I doing wrong? How can I add a context menu to the dialog grids?

Comment: See this answer <br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607576/how-to-create-jqgrid-context-menu
and bind it to the grids <b>th</b> elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that all the dialog boxes in jQuery are controlled by CSS.

Maybe you could try changing the z-index value of your context menu to make it pop-over your dialog ?