# JQGrid ContextMenu - Dynamic Menus

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, contextmenu

I have a page, which is used for building queries and running them against different entities (Kind of a query builder/generic search).

The results are displayed in JQGrid, so effectively the same grid will be used for rendering results from different entities.

This results grid has to support context menus, which will differ for each entity. So I need a way to change the context menu as per the entity. Each entity may have different number of menu items in context menu and each item may respond in a different manner (sometimes an alert, sometimes an action spawning in a different tab).

Rendering different menus (through li) is not an issue but attaching the methods to the li is proving to be a challenge. Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

I am using jquery.contextmenu-ui.js .

Following is from a sample that I picked from their (JQGrid) site

```
function initGrid() {
    $("#EntityGrid").contextMenu('cMenu'
        ,{
        bindings: { /* I would like to avoid this and pass all the actions to one method*/
            'edit': function (t) {
                editRow();
            },
            'add': function (t) {
                addRow();
            },
            'del': function (t) {
                delRow();
            }
        },
        onContextMenu: function (event, menu) {
            var rowId = $(event.target).parent("tr").attr("id")
            var grid = $("#EntityGrid");
            grid.setSelection(rowId);
            return true;
        }
    }
    );
}
```

Thanks,
Avinash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onShowMenu` callback of `contextMenu` instead of static binding using `bindings`. In the same way the `menuId` used as the first parameter of `contextMenu` could be the `id` of dynamically created div with empty `<ul>`. The `onShowMenu` has the form

```
onShowMenu: function (e, $menu) {
    // here one can clear `<ul>` child of $menu
    // and append it with "<li>" items
    return $menu;
}
```

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491939/315935) you will find an example of the code which build menu dynamically.