# how to place pager to end of top of toolbar in free jqgrid

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

free jqgrid top toolbar contains lot of buttons, select element and pager without last page button.
Buttons are wrapped to multiple lines. Central part is removed using

```
#grid_toppager_center {
    width: 0;
}
```

Since pager is in right area, there is lot of unused empty space  below and after pager:

[image: emptry space]

I tried to remove empty space using

```
#grid_toppager_center, #grid_toppager_right {
    width: 0;
}
```

and

```
    pagerpos: 'left',
```

In this case pager appears in top of toolbar buttons:

[image: top]

How to place pager to other place, for example to end of top toolbar ?

jqgrid settings:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    iconSet: "fontAwesome" ,
    autoResizing: { compact: true,widthOfVisiblePartOfSortIcon: 13 },
    toppager: true,
    viewrecords: false,
    pagerpos: 'left',
    rowList: [50, 500, 1000],
    rowNum: 50,
```

style:

```
#grid_toppager_center, #grid_toppager_right {
    width: 0;
}

.ui-pg-button-text {
    margin: 4px !important;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .ui-pg-div > span {
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button.ui-state-active {
    margin: 1px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

**Update**

I tried demo from

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/tougleButton1_iconOver2.htm

and decreased jqgrid width.

Empty space still appears:

[image: empty]

How to put buttons to this area so that they use whole grid width and wrap as many lines as nessecary ? After buttons where should be pager.

Desired is compact toolbar occupying as few rows as possible (two last buttons removed in this sample):

[image: desired2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to implement your requirements seems me the following:

First of all you remove creating unneeded elements of the pager by usage `pgbuttons: false`, `pginput: false`, `rowList: []`, `viewrecords: false` (the last two options `rowList: []`, `viewrecords: false` are already defaults).

The pager of free jqGrid 4.8 still consists from the table with one row and three cells: left, center and right. So to make the left part over the whole pager one can use the following:

```js
$("#grid_toppager_center").hide();
$("#grid_toppager_right").hide();
$("#grid_toppager_left").attr("colspan", "3");
```

The results you can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/tougleButton1_iconOver1.htm):
[image]

In general one can use still the pager, and to hide only the right part of the pager. In the case one can use

```js
$("#grid_toppager_right").hide();
$("#grid_toppager_left").attr("colspan", "2");
```

for example. See [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/tougleButton1_iconOver2.htm) which displays:

[image]

One can of cause reduce the pager by removing unneeded elements like do [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/tougleButton1_iconOver2_.htm):

[image]

**UPDATED**: The solution of your problem depends on **exact requirements** which you have. I wanted to show you the main problem which one have in the pager and navigator bar. All other adjustments can be easy made depend on what you need.

For example [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/tougleButton1_iconOver3.htm) moves the pager table *inside of* navigator bar. The results looks like on the picture below

[image]

If you need additional customization, you need to do this yourself. The last demo uses the code

```js
$("#grid_toppager_left").hide();
$("#grid_toppager_right").hide();
$("#grid_toppager_center").attr("colspan", "2");
$("#grid_toppager_center").css({width: "", "text-align": "left", "white-space": ""});
$("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable").append(
    $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">table.ui-pg-table")
);
$("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable").children().each(function() {
    $(this).css("float", "left");
});
$grid.bind("jqGridAfterGridComplete", function () {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"), $toppager = $(p.toppager);
    $toppager.find(".navtable").css("width", "");
});
```

Comment: I tried demo in answer but empty space still appears. I updated question.

Comment: @Andrus: What you tried? Which demo? In Which browsers, with which zoom? Do you have problems in *my demo* of in *your code*? ...

Comment: @Andrus: See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but if text is under buttons, it causes dancing hell. For unknown reason last button wraps to separate line. Video about this is at https://youtu.be/9_Jn616wOCk

Comment: I added `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .ui-pg-div > span {
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
` to your code and was able to reproduce dancing in chrome in 125% of zoom ( pressing 2 times Ctrl+ + ) in your sample. How to use big icons without dancing in updated sample ?

Comment: Video which shows dancing in last sample in answer is at https://youtu.be/9ptWC3_5jXM

Comment: @Andrus: I wrote you already: "If you need additional customization, you need to do this yourself." I don't want to do all your job. Probably the usage float: left in the last demo is not the best choice one should find better CSS settings. Something like `$("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable>table.ui-pg-table").css({display: "inline-block"});` will be better instead of `$("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable").children().each(function() {$(this).css("float", "left");});`

Comment: Than you very much. `$("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable>table.ui-pg-table").css({display: "inline-block"});` worked. Tablets required bigger buttons and have small screens. Can this feature added to jqgrid to make it tablet friendly?