# Free jqGrid 4.8.0 - Add buttons to toolbar

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I learn there is an option to add a toolbar to the grid by adding toolbar:[true.'top'] (example for adding an empty toolbar to the top of the grid).

How do I add buttons to that toolbar?  I know how jqGrid('navButtonAdd', nameOfPager) works and also familier with the toppager options, but don't know how to add buttons to the toolbar I just mentioned above.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqGrid have no API for manipulation of the `toolbar: [true, "top"]`. The only goal of the toolbar is a `<div>` inside of jqGrid. The CSS `width` attribute will be changed during resizing the grid, but nothing more will be done.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22717875/315935) provides (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OneFieldSearching2_.htm)) provides a practical example of the usage of the toolbar. It add information using `$("#t_" + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id)).append` to the toolbar. In case if the grid id don't contains special characters (`.`, `,` and other) one can use simplified selector `"#t_" + $grid[0].id`.

In the same way one can move the navigator buttons from the standard place to the top toolbar. It could be practical it you have many toolbar buttons. I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/NavigatorBarImTopToolbar.htm) for you which demonstrates this.

[image]

One can combine the solution with `createContexMenuFromNavigatorButtons` and `showHideColumnMenu` methods which I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29374787/315935)

The approach is close to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29048089/315935) where one wanted to have large button on top of the grid to make it more friendly for the users of Tablet PC (iPad for example).

There are exist [the feature request](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/8) with an example of adding functionality in the top toolbar. I find the idea interesting and I hope that I will find for the writing of the corresponding implementation.