# How to prepare dynamic context menu on right click in jqgrid based on row?

Tags: jqgrid, contextmenu

I require a context menu for jqgrid that can dynamically prepare context menu items (from scratch) based on selected row. Is there any solution for this? currently I am binding context menu to the jqgrid at the time of jqgrid initialization, but now I want it to be bind dynamically based on selected row.

Comment: There are many ways to implement dynamic context menu. Look at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611089/315935) fore example, which uses [jQuery-contextMenu](http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/) plugin. There are many other alternative solutions. The choice could depend on CSS framework, which you use, on the version and fork of jqGrid, which you use.

Comment: I want to make it with jqgrid. do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. jqGrid has no internal built-in context menus, but one can bind the standard `context` event on the whole grid or on every row. There are many existing plugins, which can be used *in combination* with jqGrid. The answer, which I referenced in my previous comment provides the corresponding demo. Is it what you need?

Comment: I visited the link you have provided. It is very useful thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! I'll post the summary of the information from above comments as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid has **no internal built-in context menus**, but one can bind the standard context event on the whole grid or on every row. There are many existing plugins, which can be used in combination with jqGrid. [The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611089/315935) provides an example of using [jQuery-contextMenu](http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/) plugin in combination with [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). I think that you can use close code to implement your requirements.