# Remove dancing effect in Chrome from free jqgrid toolbar buttons in font awesome icons are used

Tags: css, google-chrome, jqgrid, font-awesome, free-jqgrid

I tried demo

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FortAwesome/FontAwesome2.htm

from answer

[How to make jqgrid top toolbar custom buttons bigger like standard buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530450/how-to-make-jqgrid-top-toolbar-custom-buttons-bigger-like-standard-buttons)

in Chrome in less than 100% browser zoom level.

Hovering mouse over toolbar buttons cause toolbar to vibrate ugly.

It 100% zoon it does not occur but it occurs in every zoom level less than 100%
It does not occur in zoom level >=100% and it does not occu in Intrnet Explorer

It occurs in both top and bottom toolbars.

How to fix this ?

In my application text is below buttons and font size is 16.
I tried to replace

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .ui-pg-div>span { margin: 0 5px; font-size: 20px; }
```

with

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .ui-pg-div > span {
    margin: 1px 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

In this case dancing is a bit smaller but still occurs. How to fix this ?

If jquery ui icons are used problem doent occur.
How to fix this so that FontAwesome icons can also normally used ?

**Update**

I added styles in answer (from http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/FontAwesome4Large-borderlessOnHover3.htm ) to last demo from answer [how to place pager to end of top of toolbar in free jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041956/how-to-place-pager-to-end-of-top-of-toolbar-in-free-jqgrid)  but dancing still occurs for pager buttons and for pressed toggle button.

Also pressing disabled buttons draws border over them.
How to fix this ?

Testcase:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>https://stackoverflow.com/q/27617764/315935</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Oleg Kiriljuk">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.css">
    <style>
        html, body { font-size: 75%; }
        .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year,
        .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month {
            color: black
        }
        .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button.ui-state-active { margin: 1px; font-weight: normal; }






.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-pager .navtable,
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view > .ui-jqgrid-toppager .navtable {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

    .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button:hover, .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table.navtable .ui-pg-button.ui-state-active {
        font-weight: normal;
        border: 0 none;
        background: #b6dbf7 url("images/ui-bg_glass_75_d0e5f5_1x400.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    }

.ui-pg-table .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 3px;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table.navtable .ui-pg-button:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px;
}

.ui-jqgrid .jqgrow .ui-jqgrid-actions > .ui-pg-div:hover {
    margin: 0 1px;
    border: 0 none;
    background: #b6dbf7 url("images/ui-bg_glass_75_d0e5f5_1x400.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
}




    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <!--<script src="../jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>-->
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
    /*global $ */
    /*jslint browser: true */
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var mydata = [
                { id: "10",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: "", tax: "", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "" },
                { id: "20",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "30",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "40",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "50",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "60",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "70",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "80",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "90",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9",  note: "note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "100", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "110", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "120", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
            ],
            $grid = $("#grid"),
            initDateEdit = function (elem) {
                $(elem).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                    autoSize: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    showWeek: true
                });
            },
            initDateSearch = function (elem) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    initDateEdit(elem);
                }, 100);
            };

        $grid.jqGrid({
            data: mydata,
            colNames: ["", "Client", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Notes"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "act", template: "actions" },
                { name: "name", align: "center", width: 92, editrules: {required: true} },
                { name: "invdate", width: 72, align: "center", sorttype: "date", frozen: true,
                    formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y", reformatAfterEdit: true }, datefmt: "d-M-Y",
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch } },
                { name: "amount", width: 56, template: "number", hidden: true },
                { name: "tax", width: 35, template: "number", autoResizableMinColSize: 40, hidden: true },
                { name: "total", width: 43, template: "number", hidden: true },
                { name: "closed", width: 49, template: "booleanCheckboxFa" },
                { name: "ship_via", width: 76, align: "center", formatter: "select",
                    edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN" },
                    stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN" } },
                { name: "note", width: 43, edittype: "textarea", sortable: false }
            ],
            cmTemplate: { editable: true, autoResizable: true },
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            rowNum: 10,
            autoResizing: { compact: true },
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, "10000:All"],
            //pagerpos: "right",
            //viewrecords: true,
            //pgbuttons: false,
            //pginput: false,
            //width: 390,
            toppager: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            sortname: "invdate",
            sortorder: "desc",
            navOptions: {
                position: "center",
                addtext: "Add",
                edittext: "Edit",
                deltext: "Delete",
                searchtext: "Search",
                refreshtext: "Reload",
                viewtext: "View",
                savetext: "Save",
                canceltext: "Cancel",
                iconsOverText: true
            },
            caption: "Demonstration how to make full width navigator bar"
        }).jqGrid("navGrid", {view: true})
        .jqGrid("inlineNav")
        //.jqGrid("filterToolbar")
        .jqGrid("gridResize");

        var autoedit = true;
        $grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#grid_toppager", {
            buttonicon: "fa-star",
            caption: "Toggle",
            id: "AutoEdit",
            title: "Toggle autoedit",
            onClickButton: function (options, e) {
                var $me = $(e.currentTarget);
                $me.toggleClass("ui-state-active");
                autoedit = $me.hasClass("ui-state-active");
                $me.attr("aria-pressed", autoedit ? "true" : "false");
            }
        });
        $("#grid_toppager")
            .find(".ui-pg-button")
            .each(function (i) {
                $(this).attr({
                    tabindex: String(i),
                    role: "button"
                });
            });
        //$("#AutoEdit").attr("role", "button");
        if (autoedit) {
            $("#AutoEdit").click();
        }
        $grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#grid_toppager", {
            buttonicon: "fa-table",
            caption: "Columns",
            title: "Choose columns",
            onClickButton: function (options, e) {
                $(this).jqGrid("columnChooser");
            }
        });
        $("#grid_toppager_left").hide();
        $("#grid_toppager_right").hide();
        $("#grid_toppager_center").attr("colspan", "2");
        $("#grid_toppager_center").css({width: "", "text-align": "left", "white-space": ""});
        $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable").append(
            $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">table.ui-pg-table")
        );
        $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable").children().each(function() {
            $(this).css("float", "left");
        });
        $grid.bind("jqGridAfterGridComplete", function () {
            var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"), $toppager = $(p.toppager);
            $toppager.find(".navtable").css("width", "");
        });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outerDiv" style="margin:5px;">
        <table id="grid"></table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I use zoom 150% for example in IE10 I have the same effect. If you examine jqGrid with zoom of 150% you will see identical effect. I see the same effects with jQuery UI icons like with FontAwesome icons. I don't see currently any simple way to fix the problem. The reason is the scaling of border with `1px` under zoom. The solution will be to modify the style *dynamically* on zooming and to use the values like `1.5px` or `0.8px` for the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of "dancing" of hovered buttons is the scaling of 1px border displayed on hovering. See [the lines](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.11.4/themes/base/theme.css#L65-L75) of jQuery UI CSS. The scaling are implemented in very difficult way in different web browsers. So 1px of the border will be scaled not in the same way like 1px in margin or in pagging. So [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L502-L506) used in `ui.jqgrid.css` eliminates the "dancing" of hovered buttons only in case of zoom 100%, 200% and so on.

The only safe solution of the problem which I can suggest you is **removing of the border of hovered buttons**. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/FontAwesome4Large-borderlessOnHover.htm) uses the CSS

```css
.navtable .ui-pg-button.ui-state-hover {
    border: 0 none;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

and the hovered buttons will be displayed like on the picture below

[image]

You can change additionally the background color used on hovered buttons to display hover effect more clear. For example [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/FontAwesome4Large-borderlessOnHover1.htm) uses

```css
.navtable .ui-pg-button.ui-state-hover {
    border: 0 none;
    background: #b6dbf7 url("images/ui-bg_glass_75_d0e5f5_1x400.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

The results are shown on the next picture

[image]

**UPDATED**: To remove "dancing" in pager buttons and in the buttons of the `formatter: "actions"` one can use the following CSS for example:

```css
.ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button:hover {
    border: 0 none;
    background: #b6dbf7 url("images/ui-bg_glass_75_d0e5f5_1x400.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
}
.ui-pg-table .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 3px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table.navtable .ui-pg-button:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .jqgrow  .ui-jqgrid-actions > .ui-pg-div:hover {
    margin: 0 1px;
    border: 0 none;
    background: #b6dbf7 url("images/ui-bg_glass_75_d0e5f5_1x400.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/FontAwesome4Large-borderlessOnHover2.htm).

**UPDATED 2:** [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/dancing.htm) shows how to remove "dancing" of the pager buttons which are moved in the navigation bar. It shows additionally how to remove "dancing" of tree-state buttons. It uses CSS rule

```css
.ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button:hover,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table.navtable > .ui-pg-button.ui-state-active {
    border: 0 none;
}
.ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button:hover * {
    background-color: #b6dbf7
}
.ui-pg-table .ui-pg-table.navtable .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 3px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table.navtable > .ui-pg-button:hover,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table.navtable > .ui-pg-button.ui-state-active,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table.navtable > .ui-pg-button.ui-state-active:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table.navtable > .ui-pg-button span.fa {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .jqgrow .ui-jqgrid-actions > .ui-pg-div:hover {
    margin: 0 1px;
    border: 0 none;
}
.jqgrow .ui-jqgrid-actions > .ui-pg-div:hover > span.fa,
.jqgrow .ui-jqgrid-actions > .ui-pg-div:hover > span.ui-icon {
    background-color: #b6dbf7;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked but dancing still occurs in pager and actions buttons in this demo. How to remove dancing from pager and actions buttons also ?

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! One can remove "dancing" of other  buttons in the same way. See **UPDATED** part of my answer with the new demo.

Comment: Than you. If toobar button is in pressed state, dancing still occurs. How to remove dancing if pressed state button is in toolbar?

Comment: Style assumes nested tables for pager. If pager is placed after buttons using answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041956/how-to-place-pager-to-end-of-top-of-toolbar-in-free-jqgrid dancing in pager buttons still occurs. How to remove dancing in this case ?

Comment: @Andrus: You should just add additional CSS rules for `.ui-pg-button.ui-state-active`. See [one more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/FontAwesome4Large-borderlessOnHover3.htm).

Comment: @Andrus: Do you tried `isDisplayButtons` callback of `formatter: "actions"`  which I described in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29735149/315935)?

Comment: I tried last demo styles but dancing still occurs. I updated question and added testcase. Also pressing disabled save and other disabled buttons shows border over them

Comment: @Andrus: I posted **UPDATED 2** part. Sorry, but I can't made for your permanently CSS rules for every changes which you use. I wanted to show only the main idea: one need to remove the border and change the margin of hovered elements. The exact CSS rules depends on the exact position of elements which CSS style you need to change. You need just use Developer Tools to locale the position, create the CSS rule which will be applied and then to choose the exact value of margins which remove the "dancing".

Comment: @Andrus: I updated CSS rules in the last demo once more.

Comment: In last demo dancing effect in back. How to remove it if latest jqgrid is used ?

Comment: @Andrus: It's an examples of customization, but not the solution which will be ever supported. If you want to use non-standard layout of buttons you could need to make CSS changes (or at least verify that all still work) after publishing of new versions. I published today free jqGrid 4.13.0, which have many changes in CSS, full support of Bootsrtap and glyphicons. Look at the *standard* [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa.htm) or [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-bootstrap.htm) you see no dancing on any zoom.

Comment: @Andrus: I looked in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/dancing.htm) and made it working with minimal changes in CSS.

Comment: If bootstrap GUI style or glyph icons are used, dancing still occurs

Comment: @Andrus: I can repeat, that you have to adjust the CSS rules, which you use, if you use non-standard way. I shown you already on an example what you should do.