# How to force free jqgrid do draw frozen column borders for search toolbar

Tags: html, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

If actions column has caption "Activity"/custom settings and is frozen, free jqgrid does not draw colum borders for this column in search toolbar.

Vertical lines does not appear in search toolbar:

How to fix this so that column borders appear for Activity column in search toolbar ?
Demo in http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/FontAwesome4Large-borderlessOnHover2-frozen.htm  has borders.

In testcase styles from answer in [Remove dancing effect in Chrome from free jqgrid toolbar buttons in font awesome icons are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734580/remove-dancing-effect-in-chrome-from-free-jqgrid-toolbar-buttons-in-font-awesome)
are used to remove borders from toolbar buttons. Maybe those remove column border also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made [some changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/437b319a231048f96c7fb09a6007ca413f5bf3ba) in the code of working with frozen columns in free jqGrid. I hope that the problem is fixed now.

**UPDATED**: I examined your code and could find the reason. It's very easy: you create frozen columns by call of `setFrozenColumns` **before** creating of filter toolbar by calling `filterToolbar` (you do this inside of `loadComplete` callback). So you should **change the order of calls** of `filterToolbar` and `setFrozenColumns` or **recreate the frozen columns** by calls `destroyFrozenColumns` and `setFrozenColumns`.

Comment: I tried but problem persists. Also search toolbar background gradient in checkbox and activity columns is different than in other columns. This is also visible in picture in question.

Comment: @Andrus: See **UPDATED** part of my answer.