# How to develop two jqgrids on the same page with same context menu for both the grids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have two jqgrids on a single page. And those two are supposed to have context menus. It is possible if I have two different context menus, say 'myMenu1' and 'myMenu2'. But I would like to have only one context menu and i want to use it for both the grids and I actually took reference from the [link from oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607576/how-to-create-jqgrid-context-menu/6608787#6608787). Please suggest how can i achieve??

```
<div class="contextMenu" id="myMenu1" style="display:none">
         <ul style="width: 200px">
        <li id="edit">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" style="float:left"></span>
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana">Edit Row</span>
        </li>
        <li id="del">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" style="float:left"></span>
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana">Delete Row</span>
        </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
```

And the binding i am doing is like the below.

```
loadComplete: function() {
                      $("tr.jqgrow", this).contextMenu('myMenu1', {
                          bindings: {
                              'edit': function(trigger) {
                                if (trigger.id && trigger.id !== lastSelection) {
                                      grid_location.restoreRow(lastSelection);
                                      grid_location.editRow(trigger.id, true);
                                lastSelection = trigger.id;
                                     }

                              },
                              'del': function(trigger) {
                          if ($('#del').hasClass('ui-state-disabled') === false) {
                                      // disabled item can do be choosed
                                      if (trigger.id && trigger.id !== lastSelection) {
                                          grid_location.restoreRow(lastSelection);
                                        //grid.editRow(trigger.id, true);
                                        //lastSelection = trigger.id;
                                             }
                                      grid_location.delGridRow(trigger.id, delSettings);
                                  }
                              }
                          },
                          onContextMenu: function(event/*, menu*/) {
                              var rowId = $(event.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
                              //grid.setSelection(rowId);
                              return true;
                          }
                      });
                  }
```

Comment: which plugin are you using for context menu?

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano i am using jquery.contextmenu. Its the one that has come with jqgrid downloads(version 4.4.1).

Comment: I would like to request the jqgrid gurus like @oleg to help me as this question is very important for my project and i am an ardent follower of your jqgrid examples.

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano The below answer is very useful Crisim, But I did not use this direclty rather it gave me an  idea where was i doing mistake. I will come back with the modified and working code on tomorrow .. Thank you Crisim.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `$(event.target).closest("table")` is the reference to the current jqgrid, if there are no subgrids of course.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for local data, and I am posting the entire code over here. The only concern is that for the date picker is not picking the date if the columns of type date in the two grids have same names( or indexes). So for that I have used different names(inv_date and invdate) but in the case of server side data i am still confused.

```
onContextMenu: function(event/*, menu*/) {
    /*
      In this line we will be specifying on which grid the context menu has to perform
      and this variable 'grid' has to be used in the 'onclickSubmitLocal' function.
    */
    grid = $("#currnt_grid");
    var rowId = $(event.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: in your code you still reference myMenu2, even if it's not present.

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano Pardon me, its a typo..please check now.

Comment: @WarrenFaith In the entire code , the important part is , the variable 'grid' and setting it in the 'onContextMenu' event to the current grid on which the context menu is being opened ,because the variable 'grid' is being used in the 'onclickSubmitLocal' function to represent the current grid. And to function properly the rowid should be unique for every row across all the grids.

Comment: So how about reducing it to this important part? Nobody, really nobody will take a serious look into this mass of code.

Comment: @WarrenFaith forgive me,, i am new to stackoverflow...But trying to learn things over here.

Comment: no problem, thats why I commented instead of flagging :) Keep going and enjoy it :)