# How to create Kendo Context Menu?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, contextmenu

I need to create a context menu in kendo UI and need to add some functionality to that context menu.
I saw almost similar post in this with jqgrid, 
[How to create jqGrid Context Menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607576/how-to-create-jqgrid-context-menu) .
The same I need to implement in kendo.Its very urgent.Please help me in this, thanks

KendoGrid

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Bind with initial data
        var people = [
          { firstName: "Hasibul", lastName: "Haque", email: "hasibul2363@gmail.com" }
        , { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Smith", email: "jane.smith@kendoui.com" }
        ];

        $('#grid').kendoGrid({
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            selectable: "row",//""multiple row"",
            filterable: true

          , dataSource: { data: people, pageSize: 10 }
          , columns:
              [
                { field: "firstName", title: "First Name" }
              , { field: "lastName", title: "Last Name" }
              , { field: "email", title: "email" }
              , {
                  title: "Action",
                  template: ' <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="RemoveSelectedRow()" />'
                  , filterable: false
              }
              ]


        });

        $(".k-content").dblclick(DoubleClickAction);
    });

    function Rebind() {
        var people = [
         { firstName: "Robin", lastName: "Hood", email: "robin@gmail.com" }
       , { firstName: "Hasibul", lastName: "Haque", email: "hasibul@gm.com" }
       , { firstName: "Fauzul", lastName: "Hossain", email: "fauzul@gmail.com" }
        ];

        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.data(people);
    }

    function InsertNewRow() {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var anis = { firstName: "Anisur", lastName: "Rahaman", email: "anis.com" };
        grid.dataSource.insert(anis);
    }


    function RemoveSelectedRow() {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedRow = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        grid.dataSource.remove(selectedRow);

    }


    function IterateThroughAllRows() {
        var items = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            alert(items[i].firstName);
        }
    }

    function DoubleClickAction() {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedRow = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        alert("You have double click on " + selectedRow.firstName);
    }

    function ReadSelectedRow() {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedRow = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        alert("You have selected FirstName: " + selectedRow.firstName + " and Last Name: " + selectedRow.lastName);
    }

    function EnableSelectedIndexChangeEvent() {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.bind("change", RowSelectionChangeEvent);
    }

    function RowSelectionChangeEvent() {
        ReadSelectedRow();
    }
</script>
```

```
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Rebind" onclick="Rebind()" />
        <input type="button" value="Insert New Record" onclick="InsertNewRow()" />
        <input type="button" value="Remove Selected Row" onclick="RemoveSelectedRow()" />
        <input type="button" value="Iterate" onclick="IterateThroughAllRows()" />
        <input type="button" value="Read Selected Row" onclick="ReadSelectedRow()" />
        <input type="button" value="Enable Selected Index Chnage event" onclick="EnableSelectedIndexChangeEvent()" />
    </div>

    <div id="grid" class="k-content" >
    </div>
```

Comment: FWIW Kendo UI has its own context menu functionality nowadays: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/menu/context-menu

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get some help from **[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkappel/wVHmR/)**.

```
<ul id="testMenu">
  <li value=1>
    <img src="someurl" />
    Test 1
  </li>
  <li value=2>
    <img src="someurl" />
    Test 2
  </li>
  <li value=3>
    <img src="someurl" />
    Test 3
  </li>
</ul>
```

`li`s in this `ul` are used as context menu items.. Hope this helps...