# jqGrid context menu disable items

Tags: jqgrid, contextmenu

I'm using the context menu plugin for jqgrid. I know how to remove a menu item if not needed ([ContextMenu plugin - Example 3](http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/)).

Is there a way to show the menu item but to disable the action? Like in every other program if an action is not available in a specific context?

Thanks for your anwsers in advance. :-)
Peter

Comment: go through the link

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607576/how-to-create-jqgrid-context-menu][1]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the thread where the anwser is indirectly given.